# Awareness API is failing with status code 12

Tags: google-awareness

We are facing the below issue with Google Awareness API

```
java.lang.SecurityException: Invalid API Key for package = com.mypackage. Status code received = 12
        at android.os.Parcel.createException(Parcel.java:1966)
        at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1934)
        at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1884)
        at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.IGmsServiceBroker$Stub$zza.getService(Unknown Source:45)
        at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.BaseGmsClient.getRemoteService(Unknown Source:95)
        at com.google.android.gms.common.api.internal.zzbn.run(Unknown Source:43)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
```

We tried creating a new Keystore file and add the SHA1 in google play console, tried creating a new API key in Google Play console and add it to the manifest

In Manifest, we added API key like below

```
  <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.awareness.API_KEY"
            android:value="YOUR_API_KEY"
            tools:replace="android:value" />
```

Even though we provide the right API key we are getting a message like Invalid API KEY with status code 12. We checked the package name and the other things but still, the same crash happens.

Comment: Did you find out anything? We started getting the same this month with an old app that has not been modified for some time.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error when the user is using Google Play Services version 18.7.xxx I have submitted a ticket to the issue tracker: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/138739069

### Update

This issue has been resolved. For details, check the issue tracker link above.

Comment: This issue has been resolved. For details, check the issue tracker link above.